# What is the fastest way to compare vectors from 3D array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, compare, bigdata

Here's my example data.

```
Ycoordinate = 10; 
Xcoordinate = 12; 
Zdata = 4; 

my3Darray = zeros(Ycoordinate, Xcoordinate, Zdata);
for i = 1:Ycoordinate
    for j = 1:Xcoordinate
        my3Darray(i,j,:) = uint8(rand(Zdata,1)*64);
    end
end

my3Darray = uint8(my3Darray);
```

As you can see, there're 120 locations (Y:10 * X:12) and each location has 4 of uint8 value.

And here're my questions.

1. I want to find if there're any two or more locations have same vector of Zdata (4 of uint8 value). How can I do this?
2. My actual data will be `Ycoordinate=7000`, `Xcoordinate=7000`, `Zdata = 500`.
   So it will be around 24GB array (7000*7000*500 = 24,500,000,000 byte)
   Is it possible to find same Zdata with this huge size of array?

Additionally, my data is actually `boolean` so it is just `0` or `1` but I don't know how to allocate only "1 bit(not 1 byte)" to my data.

Comment: For your last question, rather than having `Zdata = 500` and each `uint8` holding only one bit, you could compress 8 bits into each `uint8` and reduce the size of the third dimension to 63.

Comment: That's a wonderful idea! Thanks Beaker!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will tell you how many locations have duplicate z-data vectors. The idea is to `reshape` your data in to a 2D matrix where each row represents a single column of z-data from the original matrix. The reshaped matrix will have `Xcoordinate*Ycoordinate` rows and `Zdata` columns. Then you can use the [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function to get the unique rows of this reshaped matrix, which essentially removes any duplicate z-data vectors.

You can also replace the nested loop in your code with the following line to directly generate a 3D random matrix:

```
my3Darray = uint8(rand(Ycoordinate, Xcoordinate, Zdata)*64);
```

<s>If you want to store boolean data, use [`logical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html) arrays in MATLAB.</s>

**Edit:** Follow beaker's comment above to reduce the memory footprint.

Here's the code:

```
clear
clc

Ycoordinate = 4000;
Xcoordinate = 4000;
Zdata = 63;

my3Darray = uint8(rand(Ycoordinate,Xcoordinate,Zdata)*64);

%reshape data so that each z-column becomes a row
A = reshape(my3Darray,Ycoordinate*Xcoordinate,Zdata);

[A_unique, I, J] = unique(A,'rows'); %get the unique rows of A

duplicate_count = size(A,1) - size(A_unique,1)
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Have you tried it on large arrays to see how it performs? Unfortunately, `logical` arrays still allocate 8 bits per element, so you're not really saving any memory this way.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `logical` 8 bit allocation, so yes, it doesn't save any memory. Your suggestion of compressing 8 bits into a `uint8` and reducing the third dimension to 63 makes more sense. I ran a `4000x4000x63` case on my machine in under 2 minutes.

Comment: Excellent. That's not bad for sorting a billion elements.

Comment: Thanks Savithru and Beaker!!